# Setting value if two conditions are true

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a table that contains three columns. I need to set a value in column C that depends on column A and B. If all the values in column B are the same for a fixed value in column A then each row in column C needs to say "Pass" otherwise "Fail".

In the example screenshot the status is "Pass" for all values with ID = 2 because all values in the column "Name" are the same e.g. C

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hebX9.png)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `IF` and `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)=0,"Pass","Fail")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling i was being a total noob.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA
formula in C2 and copy down
(Maybe you have to replace the semicolon with comma)

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11;A2)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11;A2;$B$2:$B$11;B2);"Pass";"Fail")
```